# Python tkinter result display

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a cipher application with tkinter.Each letter in the plain text that i want to cipher is paired with a digit of the key number and written one under the other.
I'm trying to show a result like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYuaP.png)

but my result is like this(my result is correct but i am having trouble with table display)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Liz.png)

How can I do this like in the first picture?
My code:

```
def open_win():
    class Kripto(Frame):

        def __init__(self, pencere):
            Frame.__init__(self, pencere)
            self.pencere = pencere
            Label(pencere, text="Warnings", font="Times 15 bold").place(x=40, y=540, width=81, height=21)
            Label(pencere, text="Make sure to provide valid input", font="Times 10 bold", fg="white", bg="red").place(
                x=20,
                y=560,
                width=181,
                height=16)
            Label(pencere, text="Max 50 Characters allowed", font="Times 10 bold", fg="white", bg="red").place(x=20,
                                                                                                               y=580,
                                                                                                               width=171,
                                                                                                               height=16)
            
            Label(pencere, text="Enter Text: ", relief=GROOVE, width=20).place(x=20, y=30) # TEXT : reenforcementsbeingrushed
            self.Ent1 = Entry(pencere, width=30)
            self.Ent1.place(x=170, y=30)
            self.ExitButton = Button(pencere, text="Exit  ",relief=GROOVE,font="bold", command=self.Exit).place(x=620,y=380)

            Label(pencere, text="Key: ", relief=GROOVE, width=20).place(x=20, y=90)  #KEY : 74030274
            self.Ent2 = Entry(pencere, width=30)
            self.Ent2.place(x=170, y=90)



            Button(pencere, text="Temizle", relief=GROOVE, font="bold", command=self.temizle).place(x=390, y=380)
            Button(pencere, text="Ana Menü", relief=GROOVE, font="bold").place(x=500, y=380)

            Button(pencere, text="Encrypt", relief=GROOVE, font="bold", command=self.Encrypt).place(x=50, y=150)
            Button(pencere, text="Decrypt", relief=GROOVE, font="bold", command=self.Decrypt).place(x=110, y=150)

            self.RESULT = Entry(pencere, width=60)
            self.RESULT.place(x=50, y=200, height=51)

        def temizle(self):
            self.Ent2.delete(0, 'end')
            self.Ent1.delete(0, 'end')
            self.RESULT.delete(0, 'end')

        def Exit(self):
            self.pencere.quit
            sys.exit(0)

        def Encrypt(self, target=None, shift=None):
            alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            for index in range(len(alphabet)):
                if alphabet[index] == target:
                    x = index + shift
                    y = x % len(alphabet)
                    return (alphabet[y])
            string = self.Ent1.get()
            string = string.upper()
            shiftstr = self.Ent2.get()
            encrypted_string = ''

            for index in range(len(self.Ent1.get())):
                a = index
                for index in range(len(self.Ent2.get())):
                    b = index
                    if a % len(shiftstr) == b:
                        encrypted_string += self.Encrypt(string[a], int(shiftstr[b]))

            s = encrypted_string[::-1]
            for i in range(0, len(s), 5):
                self.RESULT.delete(0, END)
                self.RESULT.insert(0, s[i:i + 5])

        def Decrypt(self):
            pass


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = Tk()
        root.title("try")
        root.geometry("700x700+50+50")
        Kripto(root).pack(side="top", fill="both")
        root.mainloop()



Button(win, text="Button", relief=GROOVE, font="bold", command=open_win).place(x=140, y=140, width=151, height=81)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Defining classes in functions is bad practice. Please read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Can you please create a minimal working example? Remove all of the unnecessary widgets/code.

Comment: Also you know that your main button will call `open_win` instead of `open_win2`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: the code was too long. i just took this part

Comment: Can you also provide the inputs you gave and the outputs you received in a code format

Comment: inputs:`reenforcementsbeingrushed` and `74030274` outputs:`KIOUU-UGRPI-IUTQE-QLGYQ-FQEIY`.@Sujay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you clear `self.RESULT` in each iteration in the following for loop:

```py
s = encrypted_string[::-1]
for i in range(0, len(s), 5):
    self.RESULT.delete(0, END)   # <- clear entry
    self.RESULT.insert(0, s[i:i + 5])
```

You can get the required result as below:

```py
s = encrypted_string[::-1]
result = "-".join(s[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(s), 5))

self.RESULT.delete(0, END)
self.RESULT.insert('end', result)
```